# WebGL performance issues with retina Macbook Pro

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a WebGL application that I am developing and I have run up against some pretty serious performance concerns with Retina Display Macbook Pros.  I am testing on a 15 inch Macbook with Intel Iris Pro GPU, rendering at full resolution, which gives me a canvas resolution of 3810x2030 with a full screen Chrome window.  My application renders about 100k vertices per frame.

Now, when I set the application to run with a device pixel ratio of 1 (meaning no retina scaling), the performance of the application is solid, never falls below 60 fps, but the image quality is unacceptable.  When I switch to the retina's device pixel ratio which is 2, the image quality dramatically improves, but my framerate plummets to around 20-30 fps.

Now, I'm no stranger to GPU programming, so the reasons why this is happening are obvious to me.  What I am wondering is, has anyone out there found any workarounds or ways to optimize WebGL drawing for ultra high resolution displays with bad GPUs like the retina Macbook Pro?   Are there any non-obvious tips or tricks people have found through trial and error to resolve this issue or at least make it slightly better?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit: Small update with an interesting discovery.  I put my browser window into an external display hooked up to the Macbook, and when rendering at a DPR of 1, the performance is even higher on the external display than it is on the macbook, even with the exact same resolution, and the image quality is much better.

So even when you render a downscaled framebuffer on a Macbook Pro, it still scales it up, which is likely what is causing the poor image quality (it is scaling it up using bilinear filtering, making it more blurry than it would be if the original image were displayed unaffected).

Comment: If you have the ability to choose DPI, have you tried keeping it at `1` but use twice as big textures instead, and scale them down?

Comment: The issue is that if the final framebuffer is not set to the retina display's maximum resolution, it still looks like crap.  The retina display is very interesting: when you render at its intended resolution, it looks amazing, but if you render at anything lower than that, it just looks like complete garbage.

Comment: It could be that you are running into (artificial) driver resolution limits. One crazy thing to try would be to run 4 webgl contexts in a 2x2 table and render to each of them with an adjusted camera. This will give you 4x api overhead but might skip around some silly limit?

Comment: Here is a good article how to handle such a problems: https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingHighDPI

Comment: This may sound unintuitive, and indeed is a bit uninformed, but the problem you describe reminds me of one I had with Java 2d API.  I overcame that by oversampling my rendering to 2x the pixels and then scaling to the target resolution.  I got the performance, image quality and resolution I wanted, but frame rate was not a consideration for me, nor was I rendering vertices.  Your "scaling up" image quality problem reminded me of this.

Comment: @starmole, I see where you're coming from, but the bottleneck is most certainly the fragment shader.  Otherwise, the entire retina macbook experience would be pure jank, which anyone who has ever used one knows it isn't.  Def appreciate the out of the box thinking though.

Comment: @Kamil I have read this article, it provides information on how to utilize the window.devicePixelRatio property to achieve native resolution inside your canvas.  This is of no help, unfortunately.

Comment: I would assume you have tested frame though put to make sure that the bottleneck is not with chrome delivering the rendered frame to the canvas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just want to give an update to all those who followed this post some closure.  I was able to get my application running above 45 FPS by simply setting the canvas option "antialias: false".  This gave a huge performance gain on high density displays, and isn't necessary since high density displays provide a large amount of built-in antialiasing.  Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and I got the solution that is the same as yours. If I read your answer earlier it would not take me so much time to find  the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some things are not hardware accelerated in Chrome on Mac OSx.

Take a look at this URL:

```
chrome://gpu/
```

If you find something that is disabled, you can potentially adjust it using:

```
chrome://flags/
```

The downside, is that if you find something that works, it isn't exactly deployable. It may give you insights into where your bottleneck is though.

(here is the full list of urls that get you to hidden and special places in chrome: `chrome://chrome-urls/`)

Comment: A helpful thought, but it doesn't really help.  I already know the bottleneck in my application is the fragment shader.  The only way to reduce calls to the fragment shader is to reduce my vertex count, which isn't a great option for me.  Appreciate the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The renderer option that helped was `renderer.setPixelRatio (1);` Fps went from 40 to 60 on the Macbook Pro. Three js R86