# Three.js antialiasing not working on iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, three.js

I'm new to three.js. But I was able to complete the project. Inorder to make the graphics better, I enabled antialiasing.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
```

But when I enabled this in iPhone 5 or iPhone 5s, the renderer stops working.

- iPhone 5 Software version is iOS 9.2.1
- iPhone 5s Software version is iOS 7.1.2
- Browser is Safari

How do is resolve this? Is there a way to disable antialiasing in these devices only?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it help you with iPhone. I faced big performance issue with antialiasing in retina displays. Actually, you usually don't need antialias in retina display because high-density displays provide built-in antialiasing.I resolved it like this:

```
var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: devicePixelRatio === 1});
```

Comment: look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261999/webgl-performance-issues-with-retina-macbook-pro